# MySQL - Update Column by Concatenating Field At Each Row

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a table as such:

```
ID  Name   SignUp          Unique
1   James  August2020      JamesAugust2020  
2   Tom    August2020      TomAugust2020
3   Dick   September2020   DickSeptember2020
4   Larry  June2020        LarryJune2020
5   Sam    July2020        SamJuly2020
6   John   July2020        JohnJuly2020
7   Frank  March2020       FrankMarch2020
8   Jason  August2020      JasonAugust2020
```

If the 'SignUp' column were to change I would like to run an update query that would concatenate and update the unique column to the new 'SignUp' date for each individual with the same 'SignUp' date.

See Example (If all 'SignUp' dates were to change from August2020 to April2020, I would like the following to happen)

```
ID  Name   SignUp          Unique
1   James  April2020       JamesApril2020  
2   Tom    April2020       TomApril2020
3   Dick   September2020   DickSeptember2020
4   Larry  June2020        LarryJune2020
5   Sam    July2020        SamJuly2020
6   John   July2020        JohnJuly2020
7   Frank  March2020       FrankMarch2020
8   Jason  April2020       JasonApril2020
```

How would I do this using an update statement in MySQL?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just create a `UNIQUE KEY (Name, Signup)` constraint on the table? Then you wouldn't need the fourth column.

Comment: @BillKarwin I am not sure of how the `UNIQUE KEY` works, I will need to do further research on this concept to correctly implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET SignUp = 'April2020',
    `Unique` = CONCAT(Name, SignUp)
WHERE SignUp = 'August2020'
```

In this assignment:

```
`Unique` = CONCAT(Name, SignUp)
```

MySql uses the changed value of `SignUp`.

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rtZNCFLD742FNb5HVgHvvN/0).
Results:

```
| ID  | Name  | SignUp        | Unique            |
| --- | ----- | ------------- | ----------------- |
| 1   | James | April2020     | JamesApril2020    |
| 2   | Tom   | April2020     | TomApril2020      |
| 3   | Dick  | September2020 | DickSeptember2020 |
| 4   | Larry | June2020      | LarryJune2020     |
| 5   | Sam   | July2020      | SamJuly2020       |
| 6   | John  | July2020      | JohnJuly2020      |
| 7   | Frank | March2020     | FrankMarch2020    |
| 8   | Jason | April2020     | JasonApril2020    |
```

Comment: Thank you, this method worked best for obtaining the results I was in search of.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `unique` to be the concatenation of the other two columns, then you should define it as a generated column:

```
alter tab t add column `unique` varchar(255) generated always as
    ( concat(name, signup) );
```

It is then generated when the table is queries and there is no need (or even possibility) of updating the column.

Comment: It appears this may be the a great option for what I am looking for as this method will cut some query-writing and work out of the picture. I will further research this concept and will determine if this can implemented in my project. Thank you. @GordonLinoff

Comment: @JeremyLewis . . . This seems like the best solution if you want a column that is always in synch with the rest of the data.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using `REPLACE()` for `Unique` column

```
UPDATE tab
   SET `SignUp` = 'April2020',
       `Unique` = REPLACE(`Unique`,'August2020', 'April2020')
 WHERE `SignUp` = 'August2020'
```

during the update of `SignUp` column

Comment: Like above, I have not used the `REPLACE` command prior. I will need to do further research to determine if his method will work for my use case. Thank you for bringing this command to my attention. @BarbarosÖzhan

Answer (score 0):

**Table structure:**

```
ID  Name   SignUp          Unique
1   James  August2020      JamesAugust2020  
2   Tom    August2020      TomAugust2020
3   Dick   September2020   DickSeptember2020
4   Larry  June2020        LarryJune2020
5   Sam    July2020        SamJuly2020
6   John   July2020        JohnJuly2020
7   Frank  March2020       FrankMarch2020
8   Jason  August2020      JasonAugust2020
```

If all 'SignUp' dates were to change from August2020 to April2020.

You can update using 2 methods:

**Method 1:**

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET SignUp='April2020',
    UNIQUE = REPLACE(UNIQUE, 'August2020', 'APRIL2020')
WHERE SignUp='August2020';
```

You can check detailed documentation of [REPLACE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_replace.asp)

**Method 2:**

Or you can try another way, [concat](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-concat-function.php) `Name` and `Unique` column

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET SignUp = 'April2020',
    `Unique` = CONCAT(Name, SignUp)
WHERE SignUp = 'August2020'
```

Comment: Have not used the `REPLACE` command before, will need to further research this concept to implement. However thank you for bringing this to my attention. @AnkitJindal